# javah Help - "No classes were specified on the command line"

Tags: java, classpath

I'm running Ubuntu Linux with Eclipse installed, and I'm trying to work with JNI
to do so I need to use javah, but it doesn't seem to be working
I have just recently installed Ubuntu and am unfamiliar with Linux/bash shells

for my eclipse project called myJNI, I have class DoJNI containing the native method.

in Terminal:

```
javah -classpath .;\home\thomas\Documents\LinuxProgramming\EclipseWorkspace\myJNI\bin\org\me\jni DoJNI
```

errors I get are:
No classes were specified on the command line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use forward slashes instead of backslashes, and a colon instead of a semi-colon:

```
javah -classpath .:/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/myJNI/bin/org/me/jni DoJNI
```

Also, I *suspect* that you don't really want org/me/jni on the classpath, but just the `bin` directory, using the classname `org.me.jni.DoJNI`:

```
javah -classpath .:/home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/myJNI/bin org.me.jni.DoJNI
```

Comment: great thanks!
so that generated the header file, but when I try to compile to a .so:
./org_me_jni_DoJNI.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC libnative  line 0 C/C++ Problem
make: *** [liblibnative.so] Error 1 libnative

I'm compiling in Eclipse C/C++

Comment: Solved it
i compiled with:
gcc -o nativelib.so -shared -fPIC mycode.c